# C# Async Await not completing

Tags: c#, async-await, dapper

I have what I think is a fairly basic flow in an asychronous web api controller. The code looks like the following:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromBody] ObjectType myObject)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    try
    {
        this.callbasicMethod();
        myObject = await myRepository.UpdateDB(myObject);
        await myRepository.DeleteSomeStuff(myObject.someProperty);
        var table = Helper.CreateDataTable(myObject.anotherProperty);
        await myRepository.InsertSomeStuff(table);
        returnOk(myObject);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The problem is that none of the database calls (importantly the update call) ever execute. If I put a break point in this method around the update call, everything works just fine. It is like some sort of race condition is happening or something. Please let me know if you have an idea on how to fix this issue or what I am doing wrong.

Also, please let me know if you need any clarification, I had to obviously obfuscate the code to protect the intellectual property of the company I work for. If it helps any, the methods that are being called are implemented asynchronously themselves calling into asynchronous dapper methods to communicate with the database.

Comment: Is there a deadlock or is just like one or more of your functions aren't even being called?

Comment: @Kirk Larkin Not sure, is there a way that I can tell if there is a deadlock? I did turn on all exceptions within the exception settings box, but nothing ever triggered. I am still new to the async world, so I am not sure of the best way to debug this.

Comment: Does the controller return anything when you call it?

Comment: As far as I can tell it is returning. I am not able to use Fiddler to see what is really happening, but if I place a break point at the return, the variable does have the correct data, and the application does what it should while that break point is there.

Comment: A few things that come to mind: is your connection string correct? Do you have the ability to run profiler on your (presumably) SQL Server and do you see your statement hitting the server? Also, what does your Repository.UpdateDB look like and how is the connection managed there?

Comment: To test for db lock try to query the db directly using ssms (or whatever you are using).  If it hangs, you are locked.  Try adding a `myRepository.Complete();` (or similar) call at the end.

Comment: All connection strings are correct, as everything works as long as there is a breakpoint. I am watching the Sql Server Profiler, and nothing is hitting the database. Once the control is returned the application does then hit the database to load all other pages just fine.

Comment: Does it matter *where* you put the breakpoint?

Comment: Strangely, it doesn't seem to matter where the break point is at. I am going to attempt to restart my machine to see if that helps.

Comment: Problem is, as often with questions about custom repositories, we don't know what's happening in your repo methods. Maybe debugging forces execution of queries in there? We can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a work around, but not a true answer to why. Basically the two database calls that were being called were to delete some data from the table and then after that had been done add some data to the same table. I wrote one stored procedure to handle this and then one method within my data layer of my application and now everything is working.